# VirtualAllocEx force allocate pages

Tags: c++, windows, memory, virtualalloc

MSDN documentation says that VirtualAllocEx

> Actual physical pages are not allocated unless/until the virtual
>   addresses are actually accessed.

I need to acces the physical address right after calling VirtualAllocEx yet i cant cause they are not allocated physically yet.

How can i force it to allocate the physicals pages with or right after VirtualAllocEx  WITHOUT accessing the virtual memory first?

Comment: Why do you need to? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to access directly to physical pages its just a project for learning more about the kernel internal, would be glad for help thanks.

Comment: The only way to directly access physical pages is to be running in kernel mode.  VirtualAllocEx is not a kernel-mode function.

Comment: note that even kernel mode can't directly access physical pages, it still has to map them to a virtual address and then access them through the virtual address.

Comment: Its my usermode program that call VirtualAllocEx and my kernel driver tries to access it.

Comment: Unless there is a way to allocate memory from kernel side for a usermode program?

Comment: @user3575889: yes, you can allocate physical memory from kernel-mode code, and map it into the user address space for a given process.  See [Memory Manager Routines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).